# How can I perform PHPunit test for multiple exeptions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova, phpunit

I want to test an array of routes to see if they all throw the

> AuthenticationException

```
$routes = [
            'bla/bla/bloe',
            'bla/bla/blie',
             etc..
          ];

public function test_not_alowed_exception(){
    foreach ($routes as $route){
       $this->assertTrowsAuthenticationError($route);
    }
}

public function assertTrowsAuthenticationError($url): void {
    // Tell PHPunit we are expecting an authentication error.
    $this->expectException(AuthenticationException::class);
    // Call the Url while being unauthenticated to cause the error.
    $this->get($url)->json();
}
```

My code works perfectly for the first iteration, However, the test stops running after the first iteration due to the exception.

The problem:

1. I test for an exception.
2. The exception is successfully thrown.
3. PHPUnit stops the test. <-- This is what exceptions do.
4. A new iteration should start, with the next URL. This does not happen.

How can I loop over a set of URLs to test them for the AuthenticationException?, Since the first exception by php design stops the script?

Comment: Due to me not being a native speaker the question might be unclear. If you have any questions please leave a comment. And I will try to clarify. I will stay online for quite a while!

Comment: Have you tried using a data provider? See https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.0/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#data-providers for the documentation

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Although I do not think the problem lies there, I will test this!

Comment: Well, if you don't think that using a data provider helps, you should explain further where the problem lies instead

Answer (score 3):

The exception will end the test in the same way an exception ends execution of the code. You can only catch one exception per test.

In general, when you need to perform the same test multiple times with different input you should use data providers.

Here's what you could do:

```
public function provider() {
      return [
        [ 'bla/bla/bloe' ],
        [ 'bla/bla/blie' ],
         etc..
      ];
}

/**
  *  @dataProvider provider
  */
public function test_not_alowed_exception($route){
     $this->assertTrowsAuthenticationError($route);
}

public function assertTrowsAuthenticationError($url): void {
    // Tell PHPunit we are expecting an authentication error.
    $this->expectException(AuthenticationException::class);
    // Call the Url while being unauthenticated to cause the error.
    $this->get($url)->json();
}
```